# Cannot read property 'getZoom' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `angularjs` and `arcgis` maps for my web application. We are displaying icons on the map. Based on the zoom level of map, those icon's size should either increase  or decrease. To do that, I have used following code:

```
var z = map.getZoom();
```

Then based on the value of `z`, I have given conditions to set the size of those icons.

But now I am getting following  error:

```
Cannot read property 'getZoom' of undefined
```

How to resolve this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that map is set correctly. in your case map is undefined.

Comment: Is it an answer or comment?

Comment: thank you so much for your answers ,yes there map object is undefined but we used so many controllers and my map is in one controller we tried to share that map object but we failed to do that

Comment: now we created a new map object by using the id of the DIV so that we are able to use the map in different controller but here one more problem came always its taking zoom level as  -1 only, even thought that zoom level is 15 or 22  whatever. can you please provide some answer for this.